# why does vb6 generate a lib file along with an activeX dll?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, dll, com

I working on a c# project. For compiling this project, I need to refer a vb6 dll and this step fails drastically(Reason unknown).
But in the vb6 project output folder,I have seen that there is a lib generated along with a dll.

I have experience in c++, but I'm net to .Net
So, can someone guide me so that I can use that generated lib in my project.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

From what I remember, the .lib file in the VB6 output folder is from an intermediate build step, not a final project output. You do need to reference the VB6 dll.

You didn't mention what problem you had referencing the VB6 dll. It would be a COM dll, so it needs to be registered with regsvr32. Then you should simply be able to add a reference to it under Project -> Add Reference, and locate the dll under the COM tab.